# Weird 'undefined' error with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am attempting to read the session value from an asp.net application in jQuery. I know that this requires either a hidden field, a page method of jQuery ajax. I chose to go with the hidden element, which is simple enough:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SessionAdmin" />
```

Then in the code behind I populate it like so

```
SessionAdmin.Value = Session("selectedcompanypriviledge").ToString().ToLower()
```

I then attempt to use it like so:

```
var isAdmin = $("#SessionAdmin").val();
alert($("#SessionAdmin").val());
if (isAdmin != "coadm" && isAdmin != "tcadm" && isAdmin!= "taagt") {
    $("#htl_gds").hide();
    $("#htl_propcode").hide();
    $("#htl_RFPId").hide();
}
else {
    //alert(isAdmin);
    $("#htl_gds").show();
    $("#htl_propcode").show();
    $("#htl_RFPId").show();
}
```

'
it works the first time wonderfully, the alert gives me what I'm expecting and the items are shown. It's when I click the next link (or any link after that) then I get 'undefined for the value of **isAdmin**. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could you add the code for the method in which you are setting `SessionAdmin.Value`?

Comment: What changes when you "click the next link"?  Is the hidden `input` element still on the page?  Has it changed in any way?  Does it have the value you expect?  Step into the JavaScript code in a debugger and examine the DOM elements, see if `#SessionAdmin` is still what you expect it to be.

Comment: @David I viewed the source and **SessionAdmin** still has the value I'm expecting to see. The hyperlinks are populated from from a query gathering hotels within a certain distance from the search point.

Comment: @PsychoCoder: How about when debugging the JavaScript?  Does `$("#SessionAdmin")` find any elements?  You "viewed the source" but if the DOM changes at all then "view source" won't tell you that.

Comment: @David the weird part is the page never reloads and I'm still losing that value. Not sure how to debug the JavaScript you are referring to

Comment: @PsychoCoder: The page doesn't have to reload in order for the DOM to change.  Debugging JavaScript is often best done using browser debugging tools, such as Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools.  You'd view the code and set breakpoints just like any debugger you're used to.  When you re-load the page your breakpoints will still be set and the code will pause at those points so you can examine the runtime state more closely.

Comment: @David I put a breakpoint in (Google Chrome Developer tools) and the first link I click I get the right value but after that it's 'undefined' and I for the life of me cannot figure out where I'm losing the value at

Comment: @PsychoCoder: Specifically what object is undefined?  When that happens at runtime, where was that object populated?  What I'm implying is that the `#SessionAdmin` element in the DOM may have changed, so that jQuery selector might not find the element again.  If that's true, it means that element has changed in some way.  Either removed or changed its `id` (or another element might have the same `id`).  That could bring you closer to a root cause.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing ASP.NET server side controls by ID you need to remember that ASP.NET mangles the actual ID rendered on the client (by prepending its parent naming container names to it. It's better to find the actual ID of the field by using a little inline script:

```
$("#<%= SessionAdmin.ClientID %>").val();
```

Now that you're accessing the value from the field correctly, any other issues are probably related to how that field's value is set in the code-behind. Make sure that code is running on every post-back in the `Page_Load` method (for example). Also make sure that you're running your JavaScript code only after the DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
    // Your existing JavaScript code here
});
```